How can I fit a model with a random intercept and slope using INLA?
I'm attempting to replicate the form of a negative-binomial GLMM that I used to run via glmmTMB::glmmTMB() using INLA::inla(). In the former it's easy to specify a random intercept per subject and a random slope for a given covariate.
set.seed(312)
my_df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("S1", "S2"), each = 50)) %>% 
         mutate(X = runif(100)) %>% 
         rowwise() %>% 
         mutate(Y = if_else(ID == "S1", 
                            rnbinom(1, mu = 5 * X, size = 3), 
                            rnbinom(1, mu = 2 * X, size = 2))) %>% 
         ungroup()
mod_glmmtmb <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(Y ~ 1 + X + (1 + X | ID), 
                                data = my_df, 
                                family = glmmTMB::nbinom2())

In INLA I think this should be the right formula:
mod_inla <- INLA::inla(Y ~ 1 + f(ID, X, model = "iid"), 
                       family = "nbinomial", 
                       data = my_df)

However, when I examine the estimated random effects, I only see values for the random intercept:
mod_inla$summary.random$ID

This is despite the fact that when I examine the fitted curves there are clearly different slopes per-subject, as shown below:

I'm specifically interested in retrieving the random slopes per-subject, so any help would be greatly appreciated !
